# Why Is my code only sending part of a Large File

Tags: java, networking

Im trying to make a Java Socket File Server but I have hit a dead end, It seems to be working until in around loop 4080 then seems to stop, Any ideas as to why this is happening? here is my code:

```
public class FileSender extends Thread{

private final int PORT = 7777;
private Socket sock;
private DataInputStream fileStream;
private OutputStream out;
private File file ;

public void run() { 

    try {
       file = new File("path");

       if(file.exists()){
           System.out.println("Found File");

           if(file.canRead()){
               System.out.println("Can Read File");
           }
       }
    this.fileStream = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));



        sock = new Socket("localhost",PORT);
        out = sock.getOutputStream();

        copyStream(fileStream, out, file);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FileSender.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}

public void copyStream(DataInputStream in, OutputStream out, File file) throws IOException{

    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

    int total = 0;

    while(file.getTotalSpace() != total){
        int r = in.read(buf);


        if(r != -1){
        out.write(buf, 0, r);
        }

        total += r;
    }

    out.flush();

    System.out.println("Total was:" + total);

}
```

}

This is My Server:

```
public class FileReceiver extends Thread {

private final int PORT = 7777;
private ServerSocket sSoc;
private DataInputStream in;

public void run() {

    try {

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

        sSoc = new ServerSocket(PORT);

        Socket conn = sSoc.accept();

        in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream()));

        File file = new File("C:\\test.rar");

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        if (file.canWrite()) {

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

            int x= 0 ;
            do {

                in.read(buf);
                System.out.println(x + " : " + buf);

                fos.write(buf);
                x++;

            } while (in.read(buf) != -1);

            System.out.println("Complete");
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FileReceiver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

}

EDIT : The program will send a small text file but onlky sends part of a Larger File.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my server I was calling in.read() twice forcing anything larger then a single buffer size to miss segments.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition in the `while` loop in `copyStream` seems wrong. Please try and change it to the following and try.

```
public void copyStream(DataInputStream in, OutputStream out, File file) throws IOException{

    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

    int total = 0;

    while(true){
        int r = in.read(buf);    

        if(r != -1){
            out.write(buf, 0, r);
            total += r;
        } else {
            break;
        }  

    }
```

Comment: unfortunatly, this does not soilve the problem. The same amount of the file is sent each time.